# How do I prevent Ubuntu from putting my monitor to sleep?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, display, sleep

Ubuntu 10.04

Under Preferences > Power Management I have changed the settings to never put the computer to sleep and never to put the display to sleep.

My display still goes to sleep and I am prompted for my password when I leave the computer unattended.

I would like to be able to hit the "Lock Screen" app I added to the top panel to lock my screen, but otherwise I would like it to just stay on.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems Ubuntu-specific. Should it not be moved to askubuntu.com? (Where I'm pretty sure it would be a dupe.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check System>Preferences>Screensaver and see if "Activate screensaver when computer is idle" is checked.

Also, if you hit `Alt + F2` and enter `gconf-editor` then navigate to `/apps/gnome-power-manager/lock` you can see if `blank screen` is checked.

Comment: Which one out of curiosity?

Comment: I believe the screensaver setting did the trick.  I also did check in /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock and blank screen is not checked.

Comment: The configuration editor shows only /apps/gconf-editor and /apps/schemas/apps/gconf-editor. The both have an entry called bookmarks and nothing else is there.

Answer (score 11):

Things have changed since this post was submitted.  Go to System Settings in the top right corner of your screen, select Brightness and Lock and set "turn screen off when inactive" to never.

hope this helps all future users.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The screen still turns off when you lock

Answer (score 5):

You can use **gsettings** for enabling and disabling monitor from going to sleep:

- Disable turning off screen

  > gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
- Enable turning off screen with 5 min delay

  > gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 300

source : https://askubuntu.com/a/788456/88543

Comment: Also works for PopOS 21.xx

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS you can click on the power button on the top right of your screen, then "Settings", then "Power", then select the "Never" option from the "Blank Screen" drop down.

Comment: Did so, but it sill goes sleepy

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to disable the monitor turning off when you lock.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

Reference: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-prevent-the-display-from-turning-off-when-screen-is-locked/

Another way is to install the application caffeine and caffeine-indicator from the ubuntu app store.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out one solution. Please check if it works. Go to settings at the top right corner. From the left navigation menu,select Power. You will find a panel with the name 'Power Saving Options'. Below that you will find an option 'Automatic suspend'. Click on it and select and deselect according to your preferences. This solution is based on Ubuntu 22.04 OS version.